# WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 OAuth OIDC How Logout code with c#?

Tags: wso2, logout, wso2-identity-server

I want to have code with c# for logout:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/OpenID+Connect+Discovery

I write this but dont work:

```
var values2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "id_token_hint", id_token }
            
           
        };
        var content2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values2);
        client = new HttpClient();
        var response3 = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:9443/oidc/logout?id_token_hint=" + id_token);
```

this have error .

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @PiraveenaParalogarajah  this is my Error: access_denied  opbs cookie not received Missing session state

Comment: Seems like opbs cookie is not sent to the backend. Identity Server uses opbs cookie to track OpenID Connect sessions. Check whether opbs cookie is sent and some browser might block third party cookies. Check your browser configuration and check the request as well